# How to filter package content in wireshark?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I am filtering package in Wireshark(version 2.0.3),the tcp package data is like this:

```
7e:02:00:00:3c:01:41:31:07:17:83:02:97:00:00:00:00:00:0c:00:c3:02:28:ba:50:06:f1:ec:c0:00:59:00:00:01:2e:16:06:30:10:46:00:01:04:00:00:e6:2f:02:02:00:00:03:02:00:00:25:04:00:00:00:00:2b:04:00:00:00:00:30:01:13:31:01:12:5e:7e
```

Now I want to find the third byte to four byte contains `00:00`,how to write the filter expression? I have tried:

```
ip[3,2] == 00:00     #in tcpdump it works

data.data[3,2] == 00:00    #data.data == 00:00,but data not just only contain:00:00
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count starts from 0 so you are looking for 2 and 3 in your example.

You can specify and group slices (what you're doing in your example), or provide a range.

```
# Combines 2 slices
frame[2,3]==0000 

# From byte position 2 include 2 bytes (e.g. 2 and 3)
frame[2:2]==0000

# Provides byte range 2 through 3
frame[2-3]==0000
```

The following syntax governs slices:

Source:  https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html

```
[i:j]    i = start_offset, j = length
[i-j]    i = start_offset, j = end_offset, inclusive.
[i]      i = start_offset, length = 1
[:j]     start_offset = 0, length = j
[i:]     start_offset = i, end_offset = end_of_field
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this filter:

```
data[3:2] == 00:00  # start from 22,get 2 byte equal to 00:00
```